# Strapi, use Auth0 to access user data in Strapi

Tags: react-native, auth0, strapi

I have a React Native app that uses Strapi for its main API.

Some of the API endpoints require authentication so I've used the Auth0 provider and that's all working fine.

A user is now able to log in and I'm securely storing their access_tokens.

So far, Auth0 only gives me an access_token, a refresh_token, an id_token (jwt containing name and email etc) and expiry times for the tokens.

But I'm wondering if it's possible to be able to store a users preferences like whether they prefer dark or light theme etc and extra info such as a user_id in Strapi and let them update it after logging in with Auth0.

The catch is that only that user should have read/write access to their own data.

I can't see any docs or guidance on this kind of thing. Has anyone else managed to implement this kind of thing and if so, a rough approach would be great!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Well, one way of the doing this is creating a `OAuthUsers` collection in strapi, which will hold basic details of a user like:

1. `first_name`
2. `last_name`
3. `email`

When a user registers on [Auth0](https://auth0.com/) and returns back to your site, you can take the basic details that were returned from the identity management platform and store it in `strapi` under the `OAuthUsers` collection.

Now, coming to your question on how to store the preferences of the user, what you can do is create another collection called `preferences` with following attributes:

1. `is_dark_theme`
2. `OAuthUser` **(Make this a `one-to-one` relation with `OAuthUsers` collection )**

Every time a logged in user updates his preferences it will first come and create an entry in this collection if not already existing. How you can check if an entry exists for a user is by using the email from the `JWT` token itself, that you attach as the `bearer` token on the `API` calls. I will assume, you already know how to decode a `JWT` token.

So a rudimentary design would be like so:

```js
const is_dark_theme = request.body.is_dark_theme; // 1 or 0 for light theme
const user = await strapi.services.OAuthUsers.find({ email: '[email from JWT]'});
const preference = await strapi.services.preferences.find({ OAuthUser: user.id });

if(preference)
await strapi.services.preferences.update({is_dark_theme}, {id: preference.id});
else
await strapi.services.preferences.create({is_dark_theme, user: user.id});
```

So per this, what will happen is the user will only be able to update his own details and never be able to touch the preferences of other users as the user will only be able to pass the `is_dark_theme` parameter from front end and rest of the information will be taken from the `JWT` token.

Comment: Interesting! That mostly sounds good. But security-wise, anyone could just cURL request to the 0AuthUsers collection and read/write from there right?

Comment: No sir. You can disable the read & write apis to `OAuthUser` in strapi for `public` user role. So that way only authenticated users will be able to request data. Additionally, you can also override the `find` method in the controller to return only that specific user's data and not all user's data. I'm assuming that you're already familiar with role management and permission management in `strapi`. So this way, the authenticated user can only request & update his own data and not of others.

Comment: So, the idea would be to cut off public users from accessing `0AuthUsers` collections apis itself. And for authenticated users, you can override the `find`, `update` & `delete` methods to not do anything by just returning false. `async create (ctx) { return false; }`. So the only method exposed would be the `create` method which can just be called to create new `0AuthUser` entry for an authenticated user when he registers newly and nothing else. So you're all covered in terms of security.